# Premature end of script headers: media ( Issue related to :rails app deployment+passenger+ubuntu+apache)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, linode

i just setup a linode server and deploy my rails 3 app on it.its up and running.The problem is that some images are not showing up in the production.locally they are perfectly working.i double checked the log file(production.log) but nothing found.then i check server error.log file that says.

```
[Sat Dec 29 22:54:14 2012] [error] [client 182.177.228.157] Premature end of script headers: media, referer: http://50.116.57.152/app?v=11&o=33

Check out http://50.116.57.152/app?v=11&o=33  for live demo.
```

Thanking in advance.

Comment: I've had this persistent problem with a Rails 2.3 application and it's extremely difficult to reproduce. It just seems to happen randomly and the only thing that "fixes" it is restarting `httpd`.

Comment: Thanks tadman,can u plz explain restarting "httpd" i'm still facing ths error.bundle of thanks in advance

Comment: You know, restart the Apache `httpd` process. Use `apachectl` or whatever your system has as an alternative like `systemctl` or `service`.

Comment: Oh thanks i figured it out.ImageMagick gem was not installed on my linode server and i used dragonfly for images thats why error was coming i just installed it and bingooooo every thing is now working perfectly...........So guys be aware if you are facing the seme problem double check all the required gems installed.thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i figured it out.ImageMagick gem was not installed on my linode server and i used dragonfly for images that's why error was coming i just installed it and bingooooo every thing is now working perfectly...........So guys be aware if you are facing the seme problem double check all the required gems installed.

Secondly, if you have installed ruby 1.9.3p360 remember it has bugs due to that request rendering does not complete. So the solution is down the ruby version from p360 to let say p327 and if you are using passenger as a web server then reinstall it. Copy 3 lines that passenger gives after installation in you apache2.cong file. restart server and this error should not occur again. 
thanks.