# JRuby + [error] [client xxxx.xx.xxx.xx] Premature end of script headers: xxxx , referer:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, jruby, production-environment

I'm using the following configuration in production

- Jruby : 1.7.13
- apache2
- passenger4.0.48

The application is running fine. When i try to upload an image its throwing apache error

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log

[error] [client xxxx.xx.xxx.xx] Premature end of script headers: xxxx , referer:
```

The mongoid-paperclip gem has been used for uploading files. Even, I have tried the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086883/premature-end-of-script-headers-media-issue-related-to-rails-app-deployment), But could not able to fix it.

Its working fine in development. But getting the above issue on production.

Please help me out!
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to reproduce this issue on my production environment. I used the same configuration for (JRuby,apache and passenger). It seems to be some issue Jruby and Passenger version. Here I did the following steps to resolve it.

- Installed imagemagick
- Changed Jruby 1.7.13 to Jruby 1.7.9
- Changed Passenger 4.0.48 to Passenger 4.0.29

Make sure that you are installing the passenger-install-apache2-module properly and all the gems should reside in /jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/

Bundle your application

Restart apache

Thats it. It resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks @user3913259. I have made the changes and now, it is working.